# Python-IGraph: Find neighbors of a node, only if connecting edges have certain attributes

Tags: python, graph, igraph, networkx, network-analysis

is there such a function premade in python-igraph (or also networkx, so I could adapt it to work in igraph), or do i have to implement it?

If it doesnt exist yet, I would outlay it like that:

1. Get the incident edges of the source node,
2. only keep edges that meet the attribute criteria (for example, only edges with attribute "major")
3. For the edges from 2., find the target nodes using the target property of the edge as  described [here](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Edge-class.html)

Any improvements welcome!

Answer (score 3):

There's no pre-made function for this in igraph, but you can try something like:

```
def filtered_neighbors(graph, node, condition):
    return [ \
        edge.source if edge.target == node else edge.source \
        for edge in graph.es[graph.incident(node)] \
        if condition(edge)
    ]
```

`condition` must be a Python callable that takes an edge and returns whether the edge can be accepted.

Comment: Thissounds like a good approach! Thanks. And by the way, why don't we extend this tho sthe shortest path func in python-graph. That way we could produce shortest paths with an edge attribute condition. I.e. in a street network, search shortest path for edges that for instance in an attribute "way" do not have value "motorway  toidentify paths not suitable for pedestrians.. or many other such things?

Comment: There are many reasons, the most serious being that the shortest path functionality is implemented in C and it is completely unaware of the fact that there's a Python layer above it. It would be quite complicated to call back to Python from the shortest path function.

Answer (score 1):

Try a list comprehension.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=3)
G.add_edge(1,3,weight = 5)
node = 1
weight3_neighbors = [neighbor for neighbor in G.neighbors_iter(node) if G.edge[node][neighbor]['weight']==3]

weight3_neighbors
> [2]
```